# matplotlib.pyplot does not show proper plot

Tags: pandas, matplotlib, plot, graph

I am trying to plot data from pandas using `matplotlib.pyplot`. But the plot shows irregular indexes in `y-axis`. How do I fix this?

[image]

Comment: Isn't it correct? It is going from the low negatives to the high positives, just like how a number line should be?

Comment: @powersource97 it is not going from low negatives to high positive. -13.7 is below -32.64.

Comment: Are your values strings?

Comment: @DavidG OH, Thanks! I used pd.to_numeric to convert them to  numbers and it worked.

Comment: @Dimanjan Oh ya, sorry, missed it...

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your data, the `Absolute Change` column is not linearly increasing or decreasing, so your plot is technically correct - the axes yticks are correct.

I recommend using the built in plotting functionality of pandas

```
import matplotlib.pylab as plt
import pandas as pd

y_ticks = [...] # whatever you want here for your yticks
df.plot(kind='scatter', x='S.N.', y='Absolute Change', yticks=y_ticks)
plt.show()
```

Comment: It has already been solved. The problem was that the values were stored as strings. So I converted them to numeric, and it worked fine!

Answer (score 0):

One thing you can do is to set your axis range by yourself by using matplotlib.pyplot.axis.

**matplotlib.pyplot.axis**

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
plt.axis([0, 10, 0, 20])
```

0,10 is for x axis range. 0,20 is for y axis range.

or you can also use matplotlib.pyplot.xlim or matplotlib.pyplot.ylim

**matplotlib.pyplot.ylim**

```
plt.ylim(-2, 2)
plt.xlim(0,10)
```

Comment: Thanks! It has been solved, the problem was that they were stored as strings.